# How to texture to make a water-stained concrete effect

Tags: texturing

I'm completely new to texturing. Water stains are wide st the top then converge in. And underneath the stains, has to be a concrete texture. Is it a possible to achieve through procedural texturing? If so, which nodes should I use?
I could also just use an image, but I'm having trouble finding images that extend as long as I need them to be.

Here is the texture i'm inspired by
[image]

This reference image is stylized, but I would like to make a bit of a more realistic texture.

Comment: 'Procedural' .... would baking the result of a simulation into an image count?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try it this way, for the water stains mix a *Noise Texture* with a gradient on Z through a *Mix Color* node in *Screen* mode, stretch the noise to make it more vertical, also give it a bit of *Distortion*. Mix the result with a *Noise Texture* that makes the basic wall texture, through a *Mix Color* in *Multiply* mode:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no idea what im doing so thank you for highlighting an image

Comment: @Clorp Hello and welcome. Please don't just reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).